# Using 16-bit addresses like foo[si] with Irvine32 (in 32-bit mode)?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, memory-address, irvine32

For some reason, while I was debugging it stopped at `mov al,data1[si]` and gave me an exception

> Exception thrown at 0x00D53668 in Week 5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x01AA6000.

May I know what was the reason?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

data1 byte "MILK",0
data2 byte 4 dup('*'),0


.code
main proc

mov CX,4
mov si,0


l1: 
mov al,data1[si]  <<EXCEPTION THROWN AT THIS LINE>>

mov data2[si],al
    
inc si  ; before go in the loop l1, cx will auto deduct by 1, then cx==0?
    
loop l1
    
mov EDX, offset data2
call WriteString
    
exit
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Is `0x01AA6000` the correct address you intended to read?

Answer (score 5):

You have tagged your question [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) and [irvine32](/questions/tagged/irvine32) which indicates that you are using 32-bit instructions, but are trying to use a 16-bit index register(=`SI`) in

```
mov al,data1[si]
```

This is (almost) guaranteed to fail. Use (and setup before) a 32-bit register like `ESI` instead:

```
mov al, byte ptr data1[esi]
```

If you're writing 32-bit code, you should generally use the 32-bit registers for your normal program flow. And the 16-bit ones only on rare, *well-thought* occasions.

Comment: Hi thank you zx485, but what if i insist to user [si] , what should i configure in order to execute it. Im using visual studiobtw!

Comment: @JoshuaTabi: Windows may not let you VirtualAlloc memory in the low 64kiB of virtual address space (which is all you can reach using 16-bit addresses).  It's probably also very inconvenient to configure your linker to map your `.data`, `.bss`, and `.rdata` sections to such low addresses, instead of their default locations.  (On Linux, see the [`mmap_min_addr`](https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr) setting, and you could use a linker script.)

Comment: @JoshuaTabi: But overall it's *very* inconvenient, and worse for performance, to try to use 16-bit addresses in 32-bit code.  So the answer to your comment is only interesting as a silly computer trick / what-if, not something you'd actually want to do.

Comment: You cannot have a 16-bit index register in 32-bit mode, because there is no instruction encoding for it. Have a look at the tables 2.2 and 2.3 (32-bit addressing forms) in the _Intel Instruction Manual_ to confirm that.

Comment: To clarify, you cannot use `SI` in indexed expressions like `mov al,data1[si]`. But of course you can use it in other instructions (generating a 16-bit prefix) like `inc si`. And, in general, this is only useful in special cases.